# Docker - Application source code updates

Tags: php, git, deployment, docker, web-deployment

I know by now that the source code of your application should be copied using `ADD` to live inside of the docker container.

This seems like a good idea, but what if I want to be able to update my application source code say - twice a day, or even more often?

Most viable solution would be to keep the source code outside of my application. Then I can keep the machine running and just update the source code using GIT.

Machine would be created like this:

`docker run -p 80:80 -v /home/adam/projects/docker-test/src:/var/www/html webserver`

This means though that if I am controlling the machine from onprem server, but the infrastructure is on EC2, each time website is opened the files would be pulled over the internet.

What is the best solution to this issue? Am I able to keep redeploying a container with updated source code but no downtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, it [should be copied with `COPY`, not `ADD`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/articles/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy), in order to limit cache invalidation.

> Most viable solution would be to keep the source code outside of my application.

Yes, but instead of referring to it through a remote source (a git server), you could have a [webhook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webhook) (like a [GitHub one](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/)) which, on each push to that git server, pull from said repo and keep an up-to-date copy of the source locally.

Then mount that local repo as a volume in your image.

Comment: I was a little sceptic about this, but I had a read and this seems like a great idea!